# Unable to compare values in dropdown box and textfield in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Please have a look at my below code

**javascript**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {   // Help for the HTML4 version.
    $('select[name=brandTxtSelect]').change(function () {

        if($(this).val()=="Select")
        {
            document.getElementById('brandTxt').readOnly = false;
            document.getElementById("brandTxt").style.display = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('brandTxt').readOnly = true;
            document.getElementById("brandTxt").style.display = "none";
            $('input[name=brandTxt]').val($(this).val());
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="brandTxt">Brand</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <select name="brandTxtSelect" class="form-control input-md">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                </select>

               <!-- <input id="textinput" name="brandTxt" type="text" placeholder="Type Drug Brand" class="form-control input-md" > -->
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input type="text" id="brandTxt" name="brandTxt" class="form-control input-md">
              </div>

            </div>
```

I am trying to make the textfield visible and enabled when "Select" is selected from the dropdown box. Unfortunately it seems always the `else` part is getting fired. I must be doing something wrong in JavaScript, please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value for "Select" is not select, is "".

Change:

```
<option value="">Select</option>
```

for:

```
<option value="Select">Select</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `val()` function would return the *value* of the selected `<option>`, not the caption.

Since the actual value of the first `<option>` is an empty string (`""`), you can simply try this instead:

```
if(!$(this).val())
```

Alternatively, if you'll omit the `value` attribute altogether, it will automatically consider the caption ("Select") as the value instead.

See [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is funny :D

You forgot, that the value of *Select* is empty, so the calue-check has to be fonde with an empty string.

```js
$('select[name=brandTxtSelect]').change(function () {
  if($(this).val()==""){
    document.getElementById('brandTxt').readOnly = false;
    document.getElementById("brandTxt").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('brandTxt').readOnly = true;
    document.getElementById("brandTxt").style.display = "none";
    $('input[name=brandTxt]').val($(this).val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="brandTxt">Brand</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select name="brandTxtSelect" class="form-control input-md">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>

               <!-- <input id="textinput" name="brandTxt" type="text" placeholder="Type Drug Brand" class="form-control input-md" > -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" id="brandTxt" name="brandTxt" class="form-control input-md">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Just do not forget to check one out of all answer as solution, cause you know: This is how it works 8-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select[name=brandTxtSelect]').change(function () {
  if($(this).val()==""){
    document.getElementById('brandTxt').readOnly = false;
    document.getElementById("brandTxt").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('brandTxt').readOnly = true;
    document.getElementById("brandTxt").style.display = "none";
    $('input[name=brandTxt]').val($(this).val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="brandTxtSelect" class="form-control input-md">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
      <option value="Option">Options</option>
    </select>
<input type="text" id="brandTxt" name="brandTxt" class="form-control input-md">
```

Try It Once